# How to check if a key exists in a word2vec trained model or not

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have trained a word2vec model using a corpus of documents with Gensim. Once the model is training, I am writing the following piece of code to get the raw feature vector of a word say "view".

```
myModel["view"]
```

However, I get a KeyError for the word which is probably because this doesn't exist as a key in the list of keys indexed by word2vec. How can I check if a key exits in the index before trying to get the raw feature vector?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

convert the model into vectors with

```
word_vectors = model.wv
```

then we can use

```
if 'word' in word_vectors.vocab
```

Answer (score 46):

Word2Vec also provides a 'vocab' member, which you can access directly.

Using a pythonistic approach:

```
if word in w2v_model.vocab:
    # Do something
```

**EDIT** Since gensim release 2.0, the API for Word2Vec changed. To access the vocabulary you should now use this:

```
if word in w2v_model.wv.vocab:
    # Do something
```

**EDIT 2** The attribute 'wv' is being deprecated and will be completed removed in gensim 4.0.0. Now it's back to the original answer by OP:

```
if word in w2v_model.vocab:
    # Do something
```

Comment: @MohitJain And how does that not provider an answer to his question? I think my answer makes perfect sense, considering this is exactly the code I use myself to solve this problem.

Comment: One liners without explanations are more suitable for comments. You can garner more upvotes if you can add brief explanation for readers like me.

Comment: If using *gensim* use rather `gensim.models.Word2Vec.wv.vocab` as indicated by rakaT below

Comment: @Titou Yes, the interface for gensim Word2Vec changed. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: How fast is this? Would it make sense to build a set from the w2v.vocab for faster access?

Answer (score 14):

The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0. Try using this:

```
if 'word' in model.wv.key_to_index:
    # do something
```

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here.

Word2Vec provides a method named **contains**('view') which returns True or False based on whether the corresponding word has been indexed or not.

Comment: For future reference, this doesn't work anomore.
`'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'contains'`

Answer (score 1):

I generally use a filter:

```
for doc in labeled_corpus:
    words = filter(lambda x: x in model.vocab, doc.words)
```

This is one simple method for getting past the KeyError on unseen words.

Answer (score 1):

as [@quemeful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69887934/15443747) has mentioned, you could do something like,

```py
if "view" in model.wv.key_to_index.keys():
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i know am getting late this post, but here is a piece of code that can handle this issue well. I myself using it in my code and it works like a charm :)

```
   size = 300 #word vector size
   word = 'food' #word token

   try:
        wordVector = model[word].reshape((1, size))
   except KeyError:
        print "not found! ",  word
```

**NOTE:**
I am using python Gensim Library for word2vec models

Answer (score 0):

to check if the word is exist in your model you can use

`word2vec_pretrained_dict = dict(zip(w2v_model.key_to_index.keys(),  w2v_model.vectors))`

where `w2v_model.key_to_index` give you dictionary of each word and sequance number

and `w2v_model.vectors` return the vectorized for of each word